# Why does this get served on every URL request?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "What!")
}

func bar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Bar!")
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", home)
  http.HandleFunc("/foo", bar)
  http.ListenAndServe(":5678", nil)
}
```

If I visit `/foo`, `bar` will run.

If I visit `/` or `/any/other/path`, `home` will run.

Any idea why this happens? How can I handle 404's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a behaviour by design - handler defined for path ending with `/` will also handle any subpath.

> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux

You have to implement you own logic for 404. Consider the following example from the golang doc:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/api/", apiHandler{})
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // The "/" pattern matches everything, so we need to check
        // that we're at the root here.
        if req.URL.Path != "/" {
                http.NotFound(w, req)
                return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the home page!")
})
```

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.Handle

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle your own 404s in `home`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is that? If I take away the root handler, 404's work. It seems that when you register a `/` handler it acts as a wildcard route.

Comment: It is a wildcard route, if you're trying to serve files, use http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer